# Does Orange API sms sends messages to Etisalat and Vodafone?

Tags: sms, orange-api

I tried to send an sms to Orange phone number and it was sent successfully! but when i tried to send to Etisalat or Vodafone number there weren't sent and the bundle decreased by two.

does orange API sms sends sms messages to Etisalat and Vodafone ?

Thank you!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a question for Orange, and not a software development question for Stack Overflow as defined in the [help]

Answer (score 1):

For which country are you referring to?

If it's Egypt, then you would need to send proof of company documents for whitelisting to contact.developer@orange.com to be able to send to other operators.

This is local legislation for Egypt.

Regards, 
D

Answer (score 0):

As @Dharmesh said I have been trying so hard but you should send government and registration papers to company developer mail contact.developer@orange.com so that your messages reached outside orange operator.

As they added more detail here :

> To send SMS to other operators in Egypt, after the approval of your sender names follow the steps in this [document](https://developer.orange.com/wp-content/uploads/SMS-Egypt-whitelisting_wj5pb3iy.pdf)